# How to save an unknown Interface to a Pointer?

Tags: delphi, pointers, interface

Can I save an unknown interface to a pointer ?

For example I have an unknown interface and want to save it to a TreeNode Data?

```
var
  X : Inknown;
```

To save :

```
....  
  Node:=TreeView1.Items.Add;
  //Node.data:=x; //compiler won't allow this
  Node.data:=@x;
...
```

To get :

```
...  
var
  //X:=Node.data; //compiler won't allow this too
  Pointer(X):=Node.data; //an exception caught
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An interface is a pointer, so you can store it as-is (don't use the `@` operator). However, to ensure the interface's lifetime, you have to increment/decrement its reference count manually for as long as the node refers to it, eg:

```
Node := TreeView1.Items.Add;
Node.Data := Pointer(x);
x._AddRef;
```

```
x := IUnknown(Node.Data);
```

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
   IUnknown(Node.Data)._Release;
end;
```

Comment: There also needs to be a call to _Release if ever Data is modified.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : Thank you very much. It's So simple while i saw too high.

Answer (score 6):

You need to capture the value of the interface reference rather than the address of the variable that holds the reference.

So, do it like this:

```
Node.Data := Pointer(X);
....
X := IInterface(Node.Data); 
// use IInterface in preference to IUnknown
```

But you must make sure that you handle the reference counting properly since this cast subverts automatic reference counting.

So, take a reference when you put the interface into the Node:

```
Node.Data := Pointer(X);
X._AddRef;
```

and call `_Release` whenever you modify `Node.Data`, or destroy the node.

---

This is rather messy, and easy to get wrong, as you found out. A better way to solve the problem is to let the compiler do the work. Define a sub-class of `TTreeNode`, and make your tree view use that sub-class. Ignore the Data property of the node and use your own property of type `IInterface`, introduced in the sub-class.

The way to make this happen is to supply an [`OnCreateNodeClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass) event handler that tells the tree view control to create nodes of your sub-class rather than plain old `TTreeNode`. And example of that technique can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611921/

Comment: Thanks David. Your suggestion better while using Treeview on UI for displaying purpose. In my case actually i'm using a kind of Virtual Treeview working on background just for init the node (all works in a single procedure).