# Storing interface pointer inside tree view nodes

Tags: delphi, pointers, interface

I'm attempting to store interface pointers in a tree view under `TTreeNode.Data` properties. While I am able to store an interface pointer (`Node.Data := Pointer(MyInterface);`) it does not seem to work the other way around (`MyInterface := ISomeInterface(Node.Data);`). It always comes out `nil`.

I've also attempted to use manual reference counting, as I've seen required in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20792648/988445). However, it is still coming out `nil` and now giving memory leaks.

```
//Clears tree view and adds drive letters
procedure TfrmMain.cmdRefreshBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Arr, O: ISuperObject;
  X: Integer;
  N, C: TTreeNode;
begin
  //First clear all items and release their interface refs
  for N in tvBrowse.Items do begin
    O:= ISuperObject(N.Data);
    O._Release;
  end;
  tvBrowse.Items.Clear;
  Arr:= ListDirectory(''); //Returns ISuperObject array listing drives
  for X := 0 to Arr.AsArray.Length-1 do begin
    O:= Arr.AsArray.O[X];
    N:= tvBrowse.Items.Add(nil, O.S['drive']+':\ ['+O.S['type']+']'); //Add root node
    N.Data:= Pointer(O); // Assign interface pointer to node data
    O._AddRef; //Manually increment interface reference count
    C:= tvBrowse.Items.AddChild(N, ''); //Add a fake child node
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.tvBrowseExpanding(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
  var AllowExpansion: Boolean);
var
  N, C: TTreeNode;
  P, A, O: ISuperObject;
  X: Integer;
begin
  //Check first node if it's a fake node
  N:= Node.getFirstChild;
  if N.Text = '' then begin //if first node is a fake node...
    P:= ISuperObject(Node.Data); // <-- P always comes out nil here???
    N.Delete; //Delete first "fake" node
    //Get child files/folders
    if Node.Parent = nil then //If root (drive) node...
      A:= ListDirectory(P.S['drive']+':\') //Returns ISuperObject array listing files/folders
    else
      A:= ListDirectory(P.S['name']); //Returns ISuperObject array listing files/folders
    for X := 0 to A.AsArray.Length-1 do begin
      O:= A.AsArray.O[X];
      C:= tvBrowse.Items.AddChild(N, O.S['name']); //Add child node
      C.Data:= Pointer(O); //Assign interface pointer to node data
      O._AddRef; //Manually increment reference count
    end;
  end;
end;
```

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: You could study the code for [TInterfaceList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TInterfaceList).

Comment: Or I could convert each interface and its contents into a record and store a record pointer instead of the interface pointer

Comment: if you put a InterfaceList, and your TTreeNode.Data point to InterfaceItem? each item in your tree view is a item in interfacelist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially you are doing this correctly. Your casts are reasonable, and you understand the need to perform manual reference counting since you are holding the reference in a field of type `Pointer` which does not perform reference counting.

```
P := ISuperObject(Node.Data);
```

If `P` is assigned the value `nil` that means that `Node.Data` is equal to `nil`. There's nothing more to say. Presumably there is some rather mundane reason for `Data` being `nil`, but it's nothing to do with the way you are casting.

Looking at your code, I would criticise it for mixing all the different concerns up together. You will find this task much easier if you can maintain a degree of isolation between the various different aspects.

One way to make life much simpler is to avoid using the untyped pointer `Data`. Instead use a custom node type that can perform proper reference counting:

```
type
  TMyTreeNode = class(TTreeNode)
  private
    FIntf: IInterface;
  property
    Intf: IInterface read FIntf write FIntf;
  end;
```

You'll need to handle the `OnCreateNodeClass` event of the tree view to get the control to create your node class.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1CreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass);
begin
  NodeClass := TMyTreeNode;
end;
```

Now whenever the tree view control creates a node instance it creates one of type `TMyTreeNode`. Which happens to have a field to contain your interface. I've typed it as `IInterface` here, but you'd use the more specific interface that fits your needs. And of course you can add whatever capability you please to your custom node type.

The mild bind to this is that you need to cast node references from `TTreeNode` (as returned by the underlying tree view control) to `TMyTreeNode` in order to gain access to the interface property. However, this bind is well worth it in my view because you can rely on the compiler to managed lifetime correctly, and so forget all about that aspect of the code. This will allow you to concentrate on your program rather than tedious boilerplate. Continuing down the path you are currently on looks like a recipe for memory leaks and access violations. Get the compiler to manage things and you can be sure to avoid any such pitfalls.

Comment: Now that's very clever.