# How to keep interfaced objects from being deleted when added to an Items.Objects[] list?

Tags: delphi

I have an interfaced object defined thusly (a list of TStringList):

```
type
  IMyList = IArrayList<TStringList>;
  TMyList = TArrayList<TStringList>;
```

I create instances to this in a function and return them to the caller. Here I get such an instance then put save it into a TListBox.Items.Objects[] property for later reference, then display it. The idea is when someone clicks on the TListBox entry, I want to get this list from Objects[] and display it.

```
procedure do_something;
var
  a_list : IMyList;
begin
  . . .
  a_list := get_some_data_in_a_list();
  // (1)
  listbox1.Items.Objects[n] := TMyList(a_list); // save ref in Items.Objects
  ShowList( a_list );
  . . .
end;
```

Here's the onClick handler for the listbox:

```
procedure TfrmMain.listbox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  n : integer;
  a_list : IMyList;
begin
  n := listbox1.ItemIndex;
  if (n < 0) then exit;
  a_list := IMyList(listbox1.Items.Objects[n]);  // (2)

  ShowList( listbox1.Items[n], a_list );
end;
```

The problem is, at line (2) above, `a_list` is `NIL`. The interface is destructing the object after it's added to the Objects[] property.

If I add this at line (1) above:

```
a_list._AddRef;
```

then at line (2) `a_list` shows up just as expected.

This seems like a hack that shouldn't be necessary, and it's probably caused by the cast to add the item into Objects[], which is required because its type is `IMyList` which isn't derived from `TObject`, whereas `TMyList` is.

How can I make this work properly without resorting to this hack?

Comment: I just recently asked an almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611118/storing-interface-pointer-inside-tree-view-nodes however I'm not sure if I'd consider it a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same issue. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll try a similar solution.

Comment: Don't forget, if you do use the "hack" `a_list._AddRef` then make sure you decrement it using `a_list._Release`

Comment: Yes, I did that in FormDestroy.

Comment: The original hack is actually storing an interface as an object. That either requires the next hack, calling `_AddRef` (and later on, `_Release`), or the solution given to Jerry Dodge. FWIW, the solution given to Jerry is already implemented in other lists (even in the VCL, IIRC) for strings, even since Delphi 2.

Comment: Solve it the same way. Use a list view and handle OnCreateItemClass.

Comment: Or even better would be to stop using the gui control as a container. Absolutely no need at all to put anything into `Objects[]`. Maintain a proper container and present a view of that from your gui.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, that is the best solution, but that would probably require a redesign. Although, I think it is OK to keep GUI stuff like icons, glyphs, colours, or similar information in the `Objects[]`. I assume that was the original purpose anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jerry Dodge, this is the same issue he was having with `TTreeView.Data` property.

I created a simple wrapper class to encapsulate `a_list` as an `IMyList` and saved that in `Objects[]` instead.

In the `TListBox.OnClick` handler, it comes out of `Objects[]` just fine, and I can access the wrapped value with no problem. It is not being destroyed this way.

In the wrapper's destructor, I simply assigned `NIL` to the `a_list` value and I have no further problems.